# How close Dropdown from vue-bootstrap-dropdown on a button clicked on vue?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Here is sample of Dropdown which works correctly.

```
<Dropdown>
  <div
    type="button"
    aria-haspopup="true"
    aria-expanded="false"
  >
  Show Dropdown
  </div>
  <template #popover>
    <button
      @click="submit"
    >
    Click me
    </button>
  </template>
</Dropdown>
```

```
<script>
method:{
  submit() {
    // How make Dropdown close
  }
}
</script>
```

I need to close dropdown after button clicked.

Answer (score 0):

- Define `showDropdown` in data
- Use `v-show="showDropdown"` on what you want to hide
- Define `@click="showDropdown = !showDropdown"` on the dropdown header to toggle the dropdown
- Set `showDropdown = false` on submit

[See a working example here](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```js
<template>
  <Dropdown>
    <div
      type="button"
      aria-haspopup="true"
      aria-expanded="false"
      @click="showDropdown = !showDropdown"
    >
      Show Dropdown
    </div>
    <div v-show="showDropdown">
      <button
        @click="submit"
      >
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  </Dropdown>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
export default defineComponent({
  data(){
    return {
      showDropdown: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
      this.showDropdown = false;
      // do more
    }
  }
  
});
</script>
```

If you need it to be a template, you can use `v-if` instead of `v-show`

Comment: you added v-show on a div not a template. It's not working on template.

Comment: @AtousaDarabiWhy do you need it to be a template?

Comment: @AtousaDarabi if you need it to be a template, you can use `v-if` instead of `v-show`